# Buffer appears faulty using ArcMap ModelBuilder -

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, buffer

I have an automatic process in ModelBuilder, where I tell it to load some points through an Excel spreadsheet, make points in shapefiles and then make a buffer. The buffer parameters are as follows:

[image]

As the "Dissolve type" parameter says, this process must dissolve all the registers ("All") and remain as one. However, I have noticed that when I run the process in ModelBuilder it does not do such a process, but instead it divides them into more records not dissolving them:

[image]

What could be happening?

The version that I am using is ArcMap 10.3.1.

Comment: What do a few of your your buffer’s input points and output polygons look like ins picture?

Comment: Always use Repair Geometry on the source feature class before using Buffer.

Comment: Can you reproduce this using the Buffer tool outside of ModelBuilder?

Comment: The points look normal and the buffering can be done without any problem outside of the model builder. Maybe I should do it with a specific field and it will work.

Comment: It should be noted that this happens to me only when I perform a merge of two batches of points with different ZONES (WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_19S y WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_18S).